# find maximum of My list

Tags: linux, unix

I have List like this

Apple 1.09
Orange 20.01
Banana 2.34

Use cut, sort, head, and tail to determine the maximum and minimum particle momenta. Which particles are they?... this is my code:

```
cat fn | cut -f4-9 -d " " | sort -n | tail -1
```

but this only show me the numerical column , but I think I need to see the whole row. so I did this :

```
cat fn | sort -nr | head -1
```

and don't sort numerically...

will you help me?

Comment: Apples, Oranges and Bananas on Serverfault... :-S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must specify which field you want to sort, by use `-k` parameter. For your example, you can do like this:

```
cat fn | sort -k 4 -nr | head -1
```

The input:

```
Apple 1.09 Orange 20.01 Banana 2.34
spple 1.09 Orange 14.01 Banana 2.34
gpple 1.09 Orange 24.01 Banana 2.34
```

The ouput:

```
gpple 1.09 Orange 24.01 Banana 2.34
Apple 1.09 Orange 20.01 Banana 2.34
spple 1.09 Orange 14.01 Banana 2.34
```

Comment: Thank you you helped me a lot :) here is my final code:             cat fn | sort -k2 -n | head -1